# How to Stabilize Hyperlapse Footage Like GoPro Hypersmooth?

Tags: stabilisation

How would you stabilise footage in post to the smoothness level of GoPro Hypersmooth automatically?

From what I have seen from online videos, the videos are way more stable than warp stabilised hyperlapses. I have also noticed that the faster (longer) the GoPro footage, the more stable it is. I suspect that they are selecting the best frames to put in the video and then run another round of electronic stabilisation. If I am not mistaken, warp stabiliser uses every single frame and warps them and thus will never be able to reach the GoPro stability of skipping unwanted frames.

Is there any way to do this automatically or semi-automatically? If GoPro can do it in a small package in seconds, it should be achievable in a powerful computer rig.

This is not only useful for handheld footage, but also gimbal/steadicam footage.

Comment: Go Pro uses data from sensors it has (Like roation) this enables a way smoother stabilisation

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to get at least close to the effect GoPro achieves (i.e. skipping frames instead of stabilising all of them)

Comment: You could try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fr9DF5iSSk4

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this out. I know how to fix this frame by frame, that's not the issue. Just figuring out what algorithm GoPro uses because it's obvious that they skip frames to stabilise - the hyperlapse gets smoother as the video gets longer since they have more frames.

Answer (score 1):

These use a combination of sensory input to counteract movement and crop the video so it resides inside of a larger one allowing it to move around and remove movement. It's a software based gimbal. I'm not sure if there is any plugins for AE or similar yet to achieve such effects. As most software is closed source that does this.